# Issues with time() when running a C musl application in docker container on arm

Tags: c, docker, arm, alpine-linux, musl

My application is unable to handle time operations like [time(2)](https://linux.die.net/man/2/time) when it runs in alpine docker container on an arm device.

What I have:
I am building a native c application which is statically linked to musl with toolchain from musl.cc (arm-linux-musleabihf-gcc). I am using latest alpine container (without image tag).

How it behaves:

- Running binary directly on arm device works as expected
- Running in alpine container on x64 device works as expected
- Running in alpine container on arm device does **not** work

What's going wrong:

- `time(NULL);` returns ((time_t) -1) and error=1: "Operation not permitted"
- The timestamps in the log outputs have cranked timestamps
- SSH handshake fails because the validity of the remote certificate is in the future.

However, if I execute `date` in container's ash the output is valid. Thus, there seems to be a problem that only occurs in alpine containers on the ARM architecture. Funnily enough, I'm switching from Ubuntu to Alpine as we had [similar problems](https://bugs.launchpad.net/cloud-images/+bug/1896443) there.

Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong?

Update #1:
Same problem on ubuntu. So the problem seems to be on any docker basis image but only on arm devices.

Update #2: Here is a minimal example
**TimeTest.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "time.h"
#include "errno.h"

int main()
{
    printf("hallo\n");

    time_t myTime;
    time_t result = time(&myTime);

    printf("result: %lld\n", result);

    if ((long)result < 0)
    {
        printf("time() error=%d: %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
    }
    else
    {
        struct tm* tm_info = localtime(&myTime);
        printf("Current local time and date: %s\n", asctime(tm_info));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)
project ("TimeTest")
if(BUILD_TARGET STREQUAL "ARM_MUSL")
    set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR arm)
    set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER /usr/bin/arm-linux-musleabi-gcc)
    set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -fno-stack-protector -mfloat-abi=softfp -static --static")
    set(CMAKE_LINK_SEARCH_END_STATIC TRUE)
endif()
add_executable (TimeTest "TimeTest.c")
```

**Output on arm device**

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ docker run --rm -it -v /tmp/TimeTest:/TimeTest alpine ash
/ # /TimeTest
hallo
result: -4696377169665647048
time() error=1: Operation not permitted
```

Comment: Shot-in-the-dark guess: it might have something to do with [vDSO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VDSO).

Comment: What happens if you call `time()` with the address of a `time_t` object?

Comment: @AndrewHenle: Both, the return value and the time_t pointed into time() have the same value: ((time_t) -1)

Comment: Could you post sample program? `which is statically linked` Ugh, does the same happen with normal linking? Could you post the compilation command you are using? Ie. some [MCVE].

Comment: @KamilCuk: I added an example. Hope the example is OK

Comment: Change `(long)result < 0` to `result == (time_t)-1`. Change `printf("result: %lld\n", result);` to `printf("result: %ju\n", (uintmax_t)result);` or `printf("result: %lld\n", (long long)result);`. So anyway, what is the current date on your machine setup to?

Comment: I am getting "Segmentation fault". `result` seems to be not `(time_t)-1`. My `printf("result: %lld\n", result);` always returns an other value

Comment: It might be [this issue](https://lwn.net/Articles/795128/).

Comment: Which version of Docker are you using?

Comment: @ionFish: I am using Docker version 19.03.8

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am able to reproduce this exactly as described in the question. On my particular ARM hardware:

```
$ docker --version
Docker version 19.03.6, build 369ce74a3c [released approx. 2020-02-12]

$ file demo
demo: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV),
statically linked, with debug_info, not stripped
```

Using `strace` we can observe this behavior inside a container launched as reported:

```
...
clock_gettime64(CLOCK_REALTIME, 0xbe9c5e10) = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
...
```

However, if we add the `--privileged` flag to the Docker command, it works:

```
# ./demo
hallo
result: 1608983884
Current local time and date: Sat Dec 26 11:58:04 2020
```

This behavior is caused by a **Docker issue**: https://gitlab.alpinelinux.org/alpine/aports/-/issues/11774, which is fixed in [this commit](https://github.com/moby/moby/commit/89fabf0f241292e929fbb2fbb794d58d8d697ab5) and rolled into Docker version `19.03.12` (?) and up.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is really an annoying problem. I am afraid that I need a work around here. What do you think about a wrapper for `__clock_gettime()`?

Answer (score 0):

ionFish has solved the puzzle. I will mark his post as answer. However, I would like to post a possible work around that I think should work in all cases. What do you guys think?

I created a wrapper for [__clock_gettime](http://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/time/clock_gettime.c) and always fallback to gettime32.

**DockerFix.c**

```
#include <time.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>

static bool __wrap___clock_gettime_fallback = false;

int __wrap___clock_gettime(clockid_t clk, struct timespec* ts)
{
    int r;

    if (!__wrap___clock_gettime_fallback)
    {
        r = __real___clock_gettime(clk, ts);
        if (!r) return r;

        if (errno == EPERM || errno == EINVAL)
        {
            printf("WARN: clock_gettime() faulted with '%s'. Using SYS_clock_gettime32 as permanent fallback. Possible cause could be a faulty Docker version!\n", strerror(errno));
            __wrap___clock_gettime_fallback = true;     // skip in future
        }
    }

    long ts32[2];
    r = syscall(SYS_clock_gettime32, clk, ts32);
    if (r == -ENOSYS && clk == CLOCK_REALTIME) {
        r = syscall(SYS_gettimeofday_time32, ts32, 0);
        ts32[1] *= 1000;
    }
    if (!r) {
        ts->tv_sec = ts32[0];
        ts->tv_nsec = ts32[1];
    }
    return r;
}

int __attribute__((weak, alias("__wrap___clock_gettime"))) clock_gettime(clockid_t clk, struct timespec* ts);
```

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS -Wl,--wrap=__clock_gettime")
add_executable (TimeTest "TimeTest.c" "DockerFix.c")
```

Answer (score 0):

for me in Raspbian SO, works correctly in a redmine image.
These is the error that it reports:

Operation not permitted - clock_gettime (Errno::EPERM)

I use privileged:true in my docker compose file